# Crystal Report - Hide specific pages

Tags: crystal-reports, header, hide

I have develped a crystal report. It must have 4 pages as default and additional 2 depending on the condition.

When the condition is success its showing all the text objects in 5th and 6th pages correctly, but in else condition, its displaying 4 pages with appropriate data and empty pages having page header in last 2 pages.

How to suppress/completely hide last 2 pages?

Pls advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a report with multiple report footer sections. You can then either adjust each report footer section to be 1 page high and add the relevant conditions and objects or alternatively add a subreport to each report footer section containing the fields/logic.

I would probably create 8 report footer sections (2 being blank) then decide whether to show the 2 blank ones or the 2 with relevant objects.

Answer (score 0):

In section expert, next to suppress use the below formula

if pagenumber in [99,100] then true 
else false

Note; Assuming 99 and 100 are last 2 pages of the report.